# Getting updates from SDE solver in Julia

Tags: julia, differential-equations, stochastic-process, differentialequations.jl

I'm solving a system of stochastic differential equations in Julia:

```
#define drift fuction
F!(du,u,t,p)=...
#define noise function 
G!(du,u,t,p)=...

#constructing and solving the problem

u_0=zeros(100,100)#initial condition
tspan=(0.0,10.0)
problem=SDEProblem(F!,G!,u_0,tspan,p)

solution=solve(problem,SOSRA(),reltol=1e-3,abstol=1e-3,save_everystep = false)
```

Now, I read [here](https://docs.sciml.ai/DiffEqDocs/stable/features/progress_bar/) that you can use the keyword argument "progress" to get updates on the remaining number of seconds to complete the run, and you can get this information with a frequency set by the argument "progress_steps":

```
solution=solve(problem,SOSRA(),reltol=1e-3,abstol=1e-3,save_everystep = false,progress=true,progress_steps=1000)
```

However, I would be interested in getting more detailed updates from the solver, like current chosen $dt$ (for adaptive algorithm), current time $t$, and current maximum value of the solution $u_{max}$. I read [here](https://www.juliabloggers.com/6-months-of-differentialequations-jl-where-we-are-and-where-we-are-going/) that this should be possible with "progress_message" at least for ODE's. However I don't know the precise syntax to make it work.
Also, I would like to possibly print these updates into a .txt file rather than having them in the terminal. Is there a way to do that?
Thanks!

I've tried

```
solution=solve(problem,SOSRA(),reltol=1e-3,abstol=1e-3,save_everystep = false, progress=true,progress_message=true)
```

But it gives an error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You likely want to use the lower level `init` and `step!` interface.

Specifically,

```
integrator = init(problem,SOSRA(),reltol=1e-3,abstol=1e-3)
step!(integrator) # takes 1 timestep
step!(integrator, .4) # steps until t==0.4
```

Comment: hi. Thanks for the reply. However i am not sure on how to extract the current dt chosen by the integrator from the code you wrote.

Comment: integrator.dt will tell you at any given step how big the next step's dt will be.